# How do I fix NullReference error in visual studio when trying to accesses uploaded file from html via c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I've been building a website and tried to add to my signup page a field where users would be able to upload their own profile photos. I intended to save the given photo to a folder within the project, but couldn't figure out why do I keep getting a `NullReferenceException`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string gender, Fname, Lname, username, pass, Sorientation, country;
    if (Request.Form["sub"] != null)
    {
        HttpPostedFile profile;
        profile = Request.Files["profile-image"];
        string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(profile.FileName);
        profile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(System.IO.Path.Combine("D:/.... /Profiles/", FileName)));    `
    }
    //..
}
```

```js
const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("profile-image");
const customBtn = document.getElementById("custom-button");
const customTxt = document.getElementById("custom-text");

customBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    realFileBtn.click();
});

realFileBtn.addEventListener("change", function () {
    if (realFileBtn.value) {
        customTxt.innerHTML = realFileBtn.value.match(
            /[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/
        )[1];
    } else {
        customTxt.innerHTML = "No image was chosen. Profile will be set as default!";
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="profile-image" name="profile-image" hidden="hidden" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.BMP"  />
<button type="button" id="custom-button" style=" padding: 4px;
  color: transparentize( rgba(255,255,255,1),0.8 );
  background-color: rgb(255, 96, 207);
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;">Upload custom image </button>
<br />
<span id="custom-text">No image was chosen. Profile will be set as default!</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `asp:FileUpload` control instead of `<input type="file" />` to be able to get posted file on request.

```
<asp:FileUpload id="ProfileImage" runat="server" id="profile-image" name="profile-image" hidden="hidden" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.BMP" />
```

Then you can access uploaded file by `ProfileImage` control

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //..
    //check if user sent a file
    if (ProfileImage.HasFile)
    {
        HttpPostedFile profile = ProfileImage.PostedFile;
        string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(profile.FileName);
        profile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(System.IO.Path.Combine("D:/.... /Profiles/", FileName)));
    }
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your form translates to as below:

Make sure you have `enctype` as `multipart/form-data`

```
<form action="enter path" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input  type="file" id="profile-image" name="profile-image" hidden="hidden" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.BMP" />
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Do null checks to avoid NullReferenceException

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase profile;
    profile = Request.Files[0]; 

    if (profile != null && profile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(profile.FileName);
        profile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("D:/.... /Profiles/", fileName)));
    }
}
```

Comment: My form has enctype setted as multipart/form-data but yet, it doesn't seem to work. I didn't understand why have you used 0 in "Request.Files[0];" and I know I should have performed a nullcheck, but that way I wouldn't see that it doesn't work when I try to use it..

Comment: @DanielDanai : Can you use HttpPostedFileBase instead of HttpPostedFile? Basically the same thing but instead of using the key to get profile i used index.

Comment: I tried using HttpPostedFileBase, but that way I couldn't get the file out of the Request.Files["profile-image"].. Is there any type of parsing necessary?

Comment: I don't think you need to cast, there is HttpPostedFileWrapper  in MVC although, are you using Windows Forms, something other than a Web Application?